# Multitasking TcpListener.AcceptSocket

Tags: multithreading, tcplistener

In the code below, StartSocketListener has been started as a Thread.  Sometimes, the processing of a message takes long enough that a couple of messages stack up (or at least that appears to be the case).  I thought I'd take the socket and start another thread with it.  I thought that passing the _HostConnection into the task would make concurrent instances of MessageFunction thread safe.  Not so, it appears.  I regularly get two kinds of errors:  one is at _HostReader.ReadString, where I either read past the end of the stream or read only a portion of the stream (as if something else has consumed part of it).  The other is at _HostWriter.Write, where I get "an established connection was aborted."  Is it obvious where I've failed to get the thread safety that I was expecting? [I am a C# developer, so the VB lambda may look awkward :) ]

```
Private Sub StartSocketListener()
    Dim _Listener As TcpListener = Nothing
    Dim _HostConnection As Socket
    Try
        _Listener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(GetIPAddress), _TCPListenerPort)
        _Listener.Start()
        While _KeepListening
            _HostConnection = _Listener.AcceptSocket
            Dim MessageFunction = Sub(socket As Socket)
                              Dim _ClientIP As String = socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString
                              Dim _HostSocketStream As NetworkStream = New NetworkStream(socket)
                              Dim _HostWriter As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(_HostSocketStream)
                              Dim _HostReader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(_HostSocketStream)
                              Try
                                  Dim _MsgXML As String = _HostReader.ReadString
                                  If _MsgXML.Trim <> "" Then
                                      If _KeepListening Then
                                          Dim _RetXML As String = ProcessMessage(_MsgXML, _ClientIP)
                                          Try
                                              _HostWriter.Write(_RetXML)
                                          Catch ex As Exception
                                              ...
                                          End Try
                                      End If
                                  End If
                              Catch ex As Exception
                                  ...
                              End Try
                              _HostReader.Close()
                              _HostWriter.Close()
                              _HostSocketStream.Close()
                              socket.Close()
                          End Sub
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Sub() MessageFunction(_HostConnection))
        End While
        _Listener.Stop()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ....
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you edited out too much code - you have an unmatched "End Sub" in there.

Comment: The first End Sub matches the anonymous Sub assigned to MessageFunction.